# Did my computer get infected with a Virus from browsing Youtube? What should I do?

Tags: desktop-computer

I was watching a Youtube video, and I then clicked on a "View all replies" link under a comment. I tried this again 2 times, and none of the clicks had worked. Immediately afterwards, three console windows appeared and promptly disappeared (I had no time to see any text on them). I turned off my computer (I don't know why, just thought that maybe if it was a virus, it would stop it? Not logical, of course). I am now using my computer without any noticeable difference, but that doesn't mean it could not have been a virus. I do not have any anti-virus software installed (except for the built-in Windows Defender). If there is a good chance this could be a virus, what should I do?

Comment: Youtube's not in the habit of infecting computers with anything more than unwated ads, uBlock Origin should be adequate for those (and improve your watching experience exponentially IMO). Maybe cookies too

Answer (score 1):

While its conceivable you might have a virus, this is very unlikely - It sounds more like javascript doing dodgy stuff and running amok.

To be safe, you might want to get Malwarebytes and do a scan with that.